# Connection to HIVE using bash

Tags: bash, unix, hadoop, hive

I made a simple bash skript, which is supposed to count columns in every table in a specified database. The problem is, that the part

```
`hive -S -e 'use '$database'; describe '$word'' | grep -e '^[a-z]' | uniq |wc -l >>MY_PROJECTS/ColumnCountList.txt`
```

consumes a lot of time because of hive connection - everytime it counts columns in every next table, it connects to hive again.

Is there any way to connect to Hive once, and then just execute commands ? It would be much faster especially when im doing it for db with 1k tables. Code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
database=pos
tables_list=`hive -S -e 'use '$database'; show tables' | grep -e '^[a-z]' | uniq`
for word in $tables_list
do
   `echo -n "$word : ">>MY_PROJECTS/ColumnCountList.txt`
   `hive -S -e 'use '$database'; describe '$word'' | grep -e '^[a-z]' | uniq |wc -l >>MY_PROJECTS/ColumnCountList.txt`
done
```

Comment: "Simple" and "efficient" are not always compatible. Since Hive does not expose metadata in tabular format, you can't do that in pure SQL, hence the extra step with `grep`. And you're stuck with an iterative approach. If you want slightly better perf, try the Beeline JDBC thin client instead of fat Hive CLI. If you really want a fast Metastore audit utility, write Java code and connect to HCatalog directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a file ( here called `desc_tbl_list.sql` ) using your bash script that contains the describe command and table name, like so:

```
describe tablename1
describe tablename2
...
```

Then run the script using hive command containing all the describe commands like so:

```
hive -f desc_tbl_list.sql
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - I did it. Only problem was that I had to  split those describes to know how many column are in specific tables, not the sum of all. I\m about to use some loop for it, np.

A new problem apperared - some tables are empty and somehow describe causes a error for them and it stops the whole query. Is there any way to handle the error to keep the whole list of describe commands executing, even if  error in one of them ?

Comment: Use hive -hiveconf hive.cli.errors.ignore=true -f desc_tbl_list.sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql as metastore database, this mysql query can give the count per table. If you want filter on database name then you have to add join to DBs.

```
select t.TBL_NAME, count(1) from TBLS t join COLUMNS_V2 c
on t.TBL_ID = c.CD_ID
group by t.TBL_NAME;
```